# System.Runtime.Caching not available in VB.net 4.0?

Tags: vb.net, caching

I have right-clicked on my project >> Properties >> Compile >> Advanced Compile Options >>
The target framework says .NET 4.0

Yet Visual Studio 2010 is not recognizing System.Runtime.Caching so I cannot start coding to improve performance of the web application.

Is this really not a .net 4.0 project? How can I confirm?

TY.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Caching

Dim dtContents As DataTable = New DataTable
dtContents = Session("Contents")

Dim cache As ObjectCache = MemoryCache.Default ??
cache.Item("cacheContents") = dtContents ??
```

Comment: Have you explicitly added a reference to System.Runtime.Caching.dll to your project?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel no, I am new to projects in general and Caching completely. Web searches have not been fruitful. Ty.

Comment: You need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Caching` to your **project** in order to reference it via `Imports` in your code.  In the solution project, right-click the References node and select Add Reference - scroll down the list in the popup window and select `System.Runtime.Caching`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on a folder in your project from **Solution Explorer**.
2. Choose **Add Reference**
3. Select `System.Runtime.Caching`

[image]